# Calculate the length of the line which represents the function in a plot

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

Lets say I have a function, that is not linear.

I want to calculate the length of the line that I would have drawn if I plot the function.

e.g I have the function $f(x)=a x^2$ and I want to calculate the length of the line drawn in the plot. Basically, its just distance$( (x, f(x)), (x + d, f(x + d))$ when $d \to 0$. Mathematica gives me $0$ which doesn't helps much...

Can anyone point me to the relevant field in mathematics?

Comment: Maybe it's just me being confused, but: if you're trying to calculate the length of any line that you could draw, why stipulate $d \to 0$?

Comment: @aricha1940 actually, I think you're right! Thanks! I'll check that out

Comment: It's no problem. The issue you were having is that if $d \to 0$, then $x + d \to x$ and $f(x+d) \to f(x)$. So you were trying to compute the distance between $(x, f(x))$ and $(x, f(x))$, which is of course $0$. Also, $d$ may not be the best variable to use here as a reader may think it means distance, when $d$ is really $\Delta x$.

Comment: Well, I still can't figure it out. I'll wait for some help...

Comment: Try applying the distance formula for two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Your two points will be $(x, ax^2)$ and $(x+\Delta x, a(x+\Delta x)^2)$.  
Unless you mean arc length, but I think this is what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, one computes *arc length* by integration. For detailed reference, consult [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) but in short you want to compute
$$
\int_a^b \sqrt{1 + |f'(x)|^2} dx
$$
so in your case of $f(x) = ax^2$ say from 0 to 1, note $f'(x) = 2ax$ so you compute
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+(2ax)^2}dx
 = \left. \frac{x}{2} \sqrt{1 + 4 a^2 x^2} + \frac{\sinh^{-1}(2ax)}{4a} \right|_{x=0}^{x=1}
 = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1 + 4 a^2} + \frac{\sinh^{-1}(2a)}{4a}
$$

**EDIT** Here is the graph:

[image: Dynamics in $a$]

In particular for large $a$ it becomes almost linear, which is easy to measure...

Comment: So, I can't hope for a simple expression... Mathematica gives a wild conditional statement... Thanks!

Comment: @QuanticProgramming Not sure if the one I typed in is so wild really. Under real values of $a$, you get real output. not sure why it is a problem?

Comment: @QuanticProgramming for example if $a=1$ the arc length is $\approx 1.48$.

Comment: @QuanticProgramming added a graph and some notes to make some intuition.